# What should I do to mitigate heavy spell damage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I keep running into encounters where the spell casters kill me.  In particular frost spells seem to be the worst.  It's not fun getting 1-shot from 300 hp by a spell.  I haven't done anything to protect myself against spells, compared to the herculean efforts I put into armor.  What should I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several methods to increase your resistance against those attacks. You can increase your magic resistance, which works against all kinds of spells, and you can increase specific elemental resistances.

The following ways can be used to increase those resistances:

- Enchanting your armor with magic or elemental resistances
- Using potions of magic or elemental resistances
- Up to 30% magic resistance from [perks in the Alteration skill tree](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alteration)
- [The Lords Stone](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Standing_Stones), grants 25% magic resistance
- 15% magic resistance from finishing the quest [The book of love](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Book_of_Love)
- Some starting races have elemental or magic resistances (e.g. Nords have 50% frost resistance)

Having conjured minions or other followers can also help to divert the attention of the spellcasters and give you the time you need to neutralize them.

Answer (score 10):

"*When confronted with a wizard, ...close the distance and hit 'im hard.*"
- [Lady Allena Benoch, Words and Philosophy](http://uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Words_and_Philosophy)

---

If you're investing perk points into Armor and/or Blocking skill perks, these should be useful when going against magic-based attacks:

[Elemental Protection](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Block#Skill_Perks), a [Block skill perk](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Block) has a 'Reduce incoming fire, frost, and shock damage by 50% when blocking with a shield' perk. It requires a skill of 50 in Block and the Deflect Arrows perk.

The shield, [Spellbreaker](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Spellbreaker#Spellbreaker), has a 38 armor rating and has a '[Ward - Deflection](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Restoration_Spells) 50 pts' enchantment. You can get it from ['The Only Cure' quest](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Only_Cure).

---

The Dawnguard DLC adds the [Aetherial Crown](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Aetherial_Crown) to the game. It is one of the three possible rewards for the ['Lost to the Ages' quest](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lost_to_the_Ages):

> It retains the power of your old Standing Stone power when you choose one, meaning that while you wear it you can have two Standing Stone powers active at the same time.

With it, you can activate both [The Lord Stone](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Lord_Stone) (adds 25% magic resistance) and [The Atronach Stone](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Atronach_Stone) (adds 50% spell absorption).

Comment: Does it consume Stamina over time when you keep the shield raised against a magic attack?

Comment: @faB It doesn't appear to be so. The only shield/block-related move that uses stamina is 'Shield Bash'. More info on which moves use stamina here: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Stamina

Answer (score 0):

take Breton female for warrior,

25% racial magic def,
15% from quest book of love,
25% from lord stone,
30% from alteration perks,
20% + 20% from necklace and ring of magic abatement (optional)

i said Breton 'female' because it gets bonus combat damage against opponents of opposite sex, i.e. males in this case, after completing agent of Dibella quest. and since most enemies in the game are males...it helps.