# How do I prevent friendly fire *from* allies?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the question, "[Would I take friendly fire damage if I had a mage as companion?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/61134/4797)", we learn that followers can deal friendly fire damage *to* the player character.

So, **how do I prevent followers, conjured/reanimated creatures and other allies from dealing friendly fire damage *to* the player character, or improve their AI to avoid them hitting the player character?**

I'm playing on the PC, so console commands and mod solutions are welcome.

Note: I'm talking about preventing friendly fire damage *from* allies *to* the player character, not the other way around. I am already aware of console commands and [in-game abilities](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Companion%27s_Insight#Companion.27s_Insight) that will prevent friendly fire damage *from* the player character *to* some allies.

Answer (score 3):

Since friendly fire (both ways) is on by default with no option in vanilla to disable, your options are either to increase your magic resistances to prevent receiving AOE or splash damage from follower, or if that is not they answer you are looking for, your only recourse is to resort to modding & console commands.

Looking around NEXUS it seems that there is no specific mod that prevents your from *receiving* damage from a companion, some rumours suggest that this mod available on NEXUS [No Friendly Fire](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/22538/?) has that option, the description on NEXUS however does not credit that.

However the suggestion

```
sifh 1
```

found here [Useful Console Commands : Elder Scrolls Skyrim](http://skyrimelder.weebly.com/console-commands.html) apparently

> Turns off friendly fire for your target, or you.

Your mileage may vary as `sifh` is the "set ignore friendly hits" function, making the target not attack back if you attack them.

However if you can target yourself or make your character the object of that command, hypothically it *might* prevent you from taking damage if you are to believe [skyrimelder](http://skyrimelder.weebly.com/console-commands.html)

Additionally:

To avoid dealing friendly damage *to* companions from AOE or splash damage, there is an ability called [Companion's Insight](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Companion%27s_Insight) found in [The Elder Scrolls V: Dragonborn](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_V:_Dragonborn) which has the following description

> "Your attacks, shouts, and destruction spells do no damage to your followers when in combat."

N.B

> Followers may still be wounded from Storm Call, Chain Lightning, Wall of Storms, Unrelenting Force, etc

Answer (score 0):

Well apart from that there is no other option for certain companions as they are melee (eg: lydia,etc) even if you put a bow in their invent they wont use it. best way is to move to the sides when you attack.

If you have a companion who can use ranged attacks (i.e: bow , staffs, magic,etc) you can avoid the friendly fire. even then they will be out  before you to take the enemies rage.

You have to position yourself in the fight so you dont attack them.

As far i have played this game this is how i play. i'm a sneaky archer/warrior(with heavy armor)

Comment: My version of Lydia has both a bow and a crossbow and will happily use both, and staffs as well. In fact I have taken all the staffs off her as she was using the wrong ones - and hurthing me and the enemies.

Answer (score -1):

This a kind of obvious answer but,you can let your follower go in front of you.Or you can make your follower a distraction so you can attack the enemy from the back or avoid the fight entirely. (AKA sneak out)